# SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE in C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm, service-not-available

Sometimes when i try to register for C2DM, I get `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. I used the code that has been given in googletochrome application when this error occurs. I just want to ask for how many times it retries andwhat is the possibility that it will register after retries. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You need to implement the retry logic yourself, e.g. you can retry in 10 seconds, and if fails again, retry again in 30 seconds, then 60, then 120, etc.

Comment: You could look at UrbanAirship as an alternative, its free to use with  the c2dm wrapper but there is a fee to use their in house developed transport system called helium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not do any retries, this is left for the developer to implement. Google recommends using exponential backoff, the algorithm can be seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff

I have found that the emulator gets a SERVICE_NOT_FOUND response when the intent is run on a new launch, all subsequent requests seem to work properly for me